# How can I use left join to count the number of results except for the first one in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I am building a custom forum.  I have two tables: threads and messages.  If you were to view a thread, the first message that would appear would be a row from the messages table that would be a max having a thread_id of whatever thread you are viewing.  I would like to include a join in my query that would find the number of replies to this thread.... so the count cannot include the first message.  Normally I would do something like this:

```
SELECT
   message_id, thread_id
FROM messages
WHERE thread_id = 1
   AND message_id != {the first message's id}
```

I am trying to combine my queries to improve load times.  How can I use joins to accomplish my above goal?

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/988cf/1) of what I have so far.  I just need to add something that would find the first message row and exclude it from the reply count.

Comment: Why not just use `count(*) - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a first one, can you just do select count(*)-1?

That SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to correspond to what you're saying - there are only 2 messages, neither of them have a thread_id as a message.